# dynamic default value sharepoint list

Tags: list, calculated-column

Is there a way to give a field a value based on the value of the last entry made in the same Sharepoint list? For example, the last made item in a list has a Title-value of 'Subject123'. What I want is that when I make a new record, he automatically fills in the Title with the value 'Subject123', and with the option to change it manually.

A calculated fields can only be calculated with fields from it's own row, but maybe there's another way that I don't know of.

Comment: You might get an idea of different ways here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153383/auto-increment-column-in-a-sharepoint-online-list, or here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17339/how-can-i-auto-increment-a-column

Comment: you can do that with infopath easily. Add current list as Data Connection to get last item field value.

Comment: @Yavuz I'm very interested how to do that with InfoPath. I was able to make a Data Connection in IP to the SharePoint List. But how can I get the latest value for the title-field? I guess I have to make a rule on the title field, with the type 'Set a field's value', but what do I fill in further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i will basicly explain with infopath. We will get list item field which ID equals dataconnection list's max ID.

1. Add current list as data connection to receive list (select desired fields)
2. Set desired field default value [image]

-> fx -> insert field or Group -> Show Advanced View -> Choose Added Data Connection (Secondary) -> dataFields -> choose desired field -> Filter Data -> Add -> Select desired field ID is equal to [use formula insert function max(ID)] ->  in the end dafault value sholud look like TestField[ID = max(ID)]

Comment: Wow, thanks! That was what I needed. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this out of the box. You need to perform the following steps:

1. Edit page **NewForm**.aspx
2. Add a **Content Editor Web Part**
3. Add code to get the latest title added. **JSOM** need. Below I detail a link to basic operations with JSON so you can take ideas.
4. Then you can use **jQuery** to complete the default value in tittle field.

[Complete basic operations using JavaScript library code in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx)